# Onclick change select options - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two date inputs & one select field. When I select dates if both are same select will become blank & if both dates are different select will show "Please select" option selected. I don't know how to do it in JavaScript.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'input[id*=dateto]',  function() {
        if($('#dateto').val == $('#datefrom').val) {
            $('#div_option').hide();
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show your code ?

Comment: *I don't know how to do it in javascript.* so learn, try and then come back, cuz until and unless you won't try you will never learn

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , seems to work

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[id*=date]').on('change', function(){

        if($('#dateto').val() == $('#datefrom').val() ) {
            $('#div_option').hide();
            return false;
        }

    });
  });
```

There the demos on https://jsfiddle.net/z2p9w944/